# dropdown-menu não funciona Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

UPDATE

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e estou fazendo o menu e ao clicar no Entre/Cadastre-se ele não apareça os itens do  `dropdown-menu` do bootstrap não funciona

```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript">
     </script>
    <script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript">
   </script>
    <script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <ul class="menu_2">

<div class="btn-group" role="group">
 <div class="btn-group" role="group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
 Entre/Cadastre-se
  <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> Meus Pedidos</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i> Meus Dados</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-group"></i> Fale Conosco</li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#">Entrar</a></li>
  <li><a href="cadastro.jsp"> Cliente novo? Cadastre-se</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <button type="button" class="carrinho btn btn-default">Carrinho <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ( )</button>
 </div>
  </ul>

   .menu_2{
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 10pt;  
  margin-top: 40px;
  color: #6495ED;

  }

 .user{
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: 12pt;
  border: 1px solid;
   float: left;
   height: 49px;
   line-height: 49px;
   font-family: "Times New Roman";

   }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não testei aqui, mas se colocar o float em `.menu_2` não da certo??

```
.menu_2{
padding: 10px;
font-size: 10pt;  
margin-top: 23px;
color: #6495ED;
float: left;
}
```

E você ja tentou utilizar Boostrap??

Algo mais ou menos como o exemplo abaixo resolveria seu caso, sem precisar ficar mexendo mais no CSS:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="btn-group" role="group">
   <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
     Entre/Cadastre-se
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> Meus Pedidos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i> Meus Dados</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-group"></i> Fale Conosco</li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Entrar</a></li>
      <li><a href="cadastro.jsp"> Cliente novo? Cadastre-se</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
   <button type="button" class="carrinho btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
</div>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Fernando VR eu atualizei a pergunta pois tive outro problema e coloquei o  código atualizado que você postou mas ao clicar no Entre/Cadastre-se os intens do dropdown-menu não aprece

Comment: @FelipePatrocinio, então primeiramente vc tem q prestar atenção nos scripts repetidos q vc está utilizando, isso pode dar conflitos e erros no seu código. vc está linkando o jquery e o bootstrap duas vezes no seu código. Precisa arrumar isso. Outra coisa, coloque sempre tudo q for javascript no final do seu código e não no início, assim ele é executado depois q o html for carregado. Da uma olhada no exemplo q eu coloquei, deixando CSS no inicio e SCRIPT no final. 
Sobre os Dropdowns, da uma olhada nesse link:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#dropdowns

Comment: Desculpe não dar mais detalhes agora, estou na correria aqui, e não ta dando tempo de analisar seu código, mas é só vc entrar no link q te passei, e ver como q tem q ser a estrutura dos dropdowns e seguir a mesma logica. É bem simples. Qualquer coisa copia o codigo q te mandei, e vai mexendo linha por linha até achar aonde seu código está dando problema.